# android.permission.ASEC_CREATE error when trying to run react app

Tags: android, react-native

I try to run "react-native android"  but got the following errors

> Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
>   com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: 
>   com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to finalize session :
>   Unknown failure (Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires
>   android.permission.ASEC_CREATE permission)

I have no problem running on emulator, but if i try to run on my phone, the error occurs

I try google but have zero results. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This problem appeared to me when I upgraded Android Studio and then Gradle.

To solve the problem I returned the version of Gradle:

```
Buildscript {
     Repositories {
         Jcenter ()
     }
     Dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.x.x'
          ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of I face this issue, had searched a lot for the solution.

Later on came to know maybe this issue occurs due to **multiDexEnabled true** in your

> app/build.gradle *in defaultConfig{}*

after Successful Sync of Project what you have to do is :

- list out your devices >> **adb devices**
- You can see your listed deviceId like 1234553231221
- run your project >> **react-native run-android --deviceId** *your_device_id*

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved after change preferred install Location sdcard to phone Storage in mobile setting. hope this help you